# Is there a way to join line above-

Tags: pycharm

I know its possible to join lines in PyCharm. It will join the current line that the caret is on with the line BELOW. Is there a way to join the current line that the caret is on with the line ABOVE it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no inbuilt way to do this in the editor. You could record a macro that achieves this then keybind that.

Something along the lines of: `cmd+shift+left` `alt+shift+left` `delete`. This would be a macro that should work in most situations.